# PCB - trace width

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

In general how do you decide what trace width to use?

I prepared a PCB layout with the trace width mainly `0.4064 mm` and couple of them are `0.3048 mm`. power ratings are 5V , 12V at max 0.4A. What would be the smallest trace width that would be fine with that ratings?

I am going to have a trace for a power unit. I will connect the outlet supply (220-240V), what trace width would you recommend for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are IPC standard calculations for trace widths based upon current draw. (IPC-2221)

These take into account freq, temperature rise, what layers of the board the traces are and many other factors.

There are many web calculators out there - http://circuitcalculator.com/wordpress/?p=25/

My absolute favorite tool for calculating many of the variables in pcb design is [a free tool from Saturn PCB](http://www.saturnpcb.com/pcb_toolkit.htm). It is free and I am not associated with them in any way.

This tool is great and will answer all your questions from above.

Comment: I should also note that you may want to look at what your board house can manufacture at a nominal cost as far as trace widths go. Normally i think that 5mil is the smallest before you start incurring extra costs. But I am sure this varies from fab house to fab house. I try to use 7mil as my smallest default trace.